# Fill empty cells based on below values if offsets are identical

Tags: excel, vba

I want to fill empty cells on column B with the below values, but just if the offsets on column A are the same, and this has to be done for thousands of different names and values.

I have this, but I need actually the opposite (such as filling top values based on below values if their offsets on column A are identical)

```
Sub Fillin()

With Range("B:B").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
          .Formula = "=IF(RC[-1]=R[-1]C[-1],R[-1]C,"""")"
          .Formula = "=IF(RC[+1]=R[-1]C[-1],R[+1]C,"""")"
          
End With
End Sub
```

For example:

```
Column A Column B
-----------------

 - BMW     blue
 - Audi    blank (should fill in as red because Audi = Audi on A)
 - Audi    red
 - Audi    green
```

Thanks!

Comment: Then change the `R[-1]` to `R[1]`

Comment: @ScottCraner thank you! I tried but displays "No empty cells were found" despite being empty cells on B that would suffice the criteria.

Comment: if there are formulas in the cells then they are not blank.  You will need to loop the range and test if `= ""`

Comment: @ScottCraner yes, there are formulas in the visible "empty cells" how can I still achieve the goal? with an if function?

Comment: I first it backwards such as taking the above value if the offsets on col A are identical, now I need the other way around but the so called "empty cells" have formulas in them...and they are thousands..

Comment: @ScottCraner I tried the above updated code but I guess it can't run 2 formulas simultaneously..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```vb
Dim c As Range

For Each c in Application.Intersect(ActiveSheet.Columns(2), ActiveSheet.UsedRange).Cells
    if Len(Trim(c.value))=0 and c.offset(0,-1).Value = c.offset(1, -1).Value Then 
        c.value=c.offset(1, 0).value
    end if
Next c
```